# Diffeomorphisms preserving "nice" smooth functions

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fractals, entropy

Let $\mathbb{R}^2\supset D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$ be the open unit disc, and $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the interior of Koch's snowflake, as constructed in Falconer's book *Fractal Geometry - Mathematical Foundations and Applications*, figure 0.2. Both $U$ and $D$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so they are both smooth submanifolds. As $U$ is simply connected (and is not the whole plane), Riemann's mapping theorem guarantees that $U$ and $D$ are biholomorphic (as subsets of $\mathbb{C}$), and in particular they are diffeomorphic as smooth submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Define $\mathcal{S}(U)$ to be the set of all smooth real valued functions on $U$, such that if we extend them by zero to $\mathbb{R}^2$ we get smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Taylor series identically zero at every point outside $U$, i.e. $$\mathcal{S}(U):=\{f\in C^\infty(U)|\exists F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)\text{ such that }F|_U=f\text{ and } T_zF\equiv0\text{ }\forall z\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus U\}.$$ Similarly define $$\mathcal{S}(D):=\{f\in C^\infty(D)|\exists F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)\text{ such that }F|_D=f\text{ and } T_zF\equiv0\text{ }\forall z\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D\}.$$

One may think of $\mathcal{S}(U)$ and $\mathcal{S}(D)$ as "Schwartz functions" on $U$ and $D$ respectively.

**My question is the following:** does there exist a diffeomorphism $\nu:D\to U$ such that $\nu^*(\mathcal{S}(U))\subset\mathcal{S}(D)$ and $(\nu^{-1})^*(\mathcal{S}(D))\subset\mathcal{S}(U)$, where as usual $\nu^*(f):=f\circ\nu$.

I suspect the answer should be negative, but at the moment cannot prove it. Any Idea or possible direction will be very much appreciated!